# How to get a row count in SwiftUI List

Tags: list, swiftui, count

I am trying to display the number of rows in a section in its header as shown below as COUNTHERE. The issue I'm running into is that I can't put any code inside the if statement that is not a view so I can't compute anything. Ideas?

```
struct Day1View: View {

var displayEmployees: [Employee]

var body: some View {
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Early (\(COUNTHERE)")) {
            ForEach(displayEmployees) { employee in
                if employee.shift == .early {
                    switch employee.post {
                    case .kitchen : Text(employee.name).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    case .floor : Text(employee.name).foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    case .upstairs : Text(employee.name).foregroundColor(.red)
                    case .greeting : Text(employee.name).foregroundColor(.green)
                    default : Text(employee.name).foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the section you showed is only for `.early` shift employees, you can get the count using a filtered version of the original array:

```
displayEmployees.filter({$0.shift == .early}).count
```

So your section becomes:

```
Section(header: Text("Early (\(displayEmployees.filter({$0.shift == .early}).count)")) {
```

Or, you can add a new computed property for the count:

```
var displayCount: Int {
    return displayEmployees.filter({$0.shift == .early}).count
}
...
Section(header: Text("Early (\(displayCount)")) {
```